# Restricting Input to numbers only(-100.00 to 100.00) in a HTML input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to restrict html input field to accept numbers only
The JS code is working fine with English keyboard on an android device but when i change keyboard to Japaneses it starts accepting Japaneses characters.

**(Update: Japanese input problem solved only - and decimal point is not being entered)**

**Here is the HTML**

`<input type='text' style='height: 100%;'  name='lmt_c13' id='lmt_c13' isNumeric='true'` `onblur='updateJudgment(this);' onkeyup='removeSpaces(this);' onkeypress='return` `isNumberKey(event,this);' class='txtCtrl' >0</input>`

**and here is the JS code**

```
function isNumberKey(evt, control) {


    if ($(control).attr("isNumeric") == "true") {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) || charCode == 13)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
};
```

the input I want in this input field in something like `-12.24` and `23.78`

Answer (score 1):

See the

```js
// Restricts input for each element in the set of matched elements to the given inputFilter.
(function($) {
  $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      } else {
        this.value = "";
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));


// Install input filters.
$("#intTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^-?\d*$/.test(value); });
$("#uintTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value); });
$("#intLimitTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value) && (value === "" || parseInt(value) <= 500); });
$("#floatTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^-?\d*[.,]?\d*$/.test(value); });
$("#currencyTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^-?\d*[.,]?\d{0,2}$/.test(value); });
$("#latinTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^[a-z]*$/i.test(value); });
$("#hexTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^[0-9a-f]*$/i.test(value); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>jQuery input filter showcase</h2>
<p>Supports Copy+Paste, Drag+Drop, keyboard shortcuts, context menu operations, non-typeable keys, the caret position, different keyboard layouts, and <a href="https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event" target="_blank">all browsers since IE 9</a>.</p>
<p>There is also a <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/emkey08/zgvtjc51" target="_blank">pure JavaScript version</a> of this (without jQuery).</p>
<table>
  <tr><td>Integer</td><td><input id="intTextBox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Integer &gt;= 0</td><td><input id="uintTextBox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Integer &gt;= 0 and &lt;= 500</td><td><input id="intLimitTextBox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Float (use . or , as decimal separator)</td><td><input id="floatTextBox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Currency (at most two decimal places)</td><td><input id="currencyTextBox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>A-Z only</td><td><input id="latinTextBox"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hexadecimal</td><td><input id="hexTextBox"></td></tr>
</table>
```

for more input filter examples. Also note that you still must do server side validation!

If you want to know more about regular expressions see this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Could you please add some explanation how your regex is solving a question about Javascript.

Comment: If you want to know more about regular expressions see this link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

For decimal point allow, You can add below condition :: || charCode == 46

```
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) || charCode == 13 || charCode == 46 )
```

Or if you want to test decimal validation then

```
function CheckDecimal(inputtxt)   
{   
    var decimal=  /^[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/;   
    if(inputtxt.value.match(decimal))   
    {   
        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {   
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

i think me i'll do this: (using regular expressions)

```
    function isNumberKey(control) {
        if ($(control).attr("isNumeric") == "true") {
            var regex = /^[0-9.-]$/;
            var _event = event || window.event;
            var key = _event.keyCode || _event.which;
            key = String.fromCharCode(key);
            if(!regex.test(key)) {
                //alert(key);
                _event.returnValue = false;
                if (_event.preventDefault)
                    _event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    };

    function isDecimal(control) {
        if ($(control).attr("isNumeric") == "true") {
            var regex = /^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$/;
            str = $(control)[0].value;
            var _event = event || window.event;
            if(!regex.test(str)) {
                var m = str.match(/^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*/g);
                $(control)[0].value = m[0];
                _event.returnValue = false;
                if (_event.preventDefault)
                    _event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    };
```

and my html:

```
<input type='text' style='height: 20px;'  name='lmt_c13' id='lmt_c13' isNumeric='true' onblur='updateJudgment(this);' onkeyup='isDecimal(this);' onkeypress='isNumberKey(this);' class='txtCtrl' value='0' />
```

please try it and tell me if it works.